# Summary of analyst views

Tags: recommendation

Is there a service (report, webpage, etc) that summarize views of different investment banks, research companies at a regional market level.

For example:

```
Equities
US: JP Morgan: Overweight; BCA: Neutral; BofA: Overweight; UBS: Overweight.
Eurozone: BCA: Neutral; BofA: Neutral; Goldman Sachs: Overweight.
Etc.

Fixed income
Etc.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this information?  Do you just want to know whether they have excessive administrative costs?  I'm assuming that's what overweight means, rather than reflections of portfolios or strategies.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on what do you mean by the "excessive admin costs"?

Comment: You tell me, that was a guess.  What are you trying to learn?

Answer (score 1):

There are several companies that offer this service.  Two of the most well-known and widely-cited such services are [First Call](http://thomsonreuters.com/estimates/), a division of Thomson Reuters, and [Zacks Investment Research](http://www.zacks.com/).  They offer a variety of interfaces to their data, including human- and machine-readable formats and historical archives.

The only catch is that it costs thousands of dollars to subscribe. :)

Check out Reuters's info PDF [here](http://thomsonreuters.com/products/financial-risk/content/07_004/thomson-reuters-estimates-fact-sheet.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact format you are looking for you may want to contract with a developer to build a custom dashboard.  Don't forget to check with your online broker to see what customization features are available.

Using the website below, I was able to add some financial stocks to a list, and navigate the list via tabs.  NASDAQ combines recommendations from multiple analysts, so you get a broad view.

Another thought is adding financial sector etfs by region to the list so you can quickly glance at the sector as a whole.

http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/jpm/recommendations

[image: NASDAQ Symbol List]

Hope this gave you some ideas!